# How to send data from Client (C) to Server (nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, arduino

I am doing a project which connects client (written in C) and Server (written in nodejs), and I want to change the way of sending data to server. Initially, data is sent by GET method:

String s = "GET /" + temp + ":3000/?" + data + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";

Now I want to send data with JSON format, so is there any way to do that, and how server (nodejs) can handle the JSON format data?

Answer (score 0):

As you undoubtedly know, there are **two** methods of sending data to a host using the HTTP protocol:  `GET` and `POST`.

`GET` includes all of the data-to-be-sent as part of the URL-string itself, *e.g.* `http://www.foo.bar?bletch=foo&y2=plugh` ...

... which necessarily means that *everything* that you wished to transmit to the host *must* conform to the very-stringent syntactic requirements of "a URL."

... *uh uh,* **much** too-restrictive for JSON!

Therefore, JSON content is always sent using `POST`, which embeds the data in an entirely-separate portion of the HTTP request packet. Although the data continues to consist of "characters," it is not subject to the same *(prohibitive ...)* strictures.